# Text writes over itself instead of creating a new line in R session

Tags: r, unix

I am running an R session on the Unix cluster, and whenever I reach a certain amount of characters, instead of starting on the new line, the text starts to write over itself at the beginning. So, for example, it should look like this:

```
foo <- read.table("/file/buried/deep/within/lots/of/folders/makes/for/a
/long/name.txt")
```

but instead it looks like this:

```
ame.txt")read.table("/file/buried/deep/within/lots/of/folders/makes/for/a/long/na
```

because the text is wrapping around and starting again at the beginning of the line.

I've changed my `width` parameter in the `options()` function, but no such luck.

ETA: I am running R on the command line in a Unix environment

Comment: I'm having difficulty in reproducing the issue that you specify. what happens if you break it into two lines like: filename <- "long_file_name"; read.table(filename); Do you get the same problem when you first define a character string that contains the file name?

Comment: You should add more information here. Are you running an interactive R session in the console (rather than, say, Rstudio)? Which console program are you using? What happens in the same console outside of an R session - I.e. are you certain that this is an R issue.

Comment: Fred, yes, if I were to break the commands up into smaller commands, I wouldn't run into this issue. I seem to be limited to about 80 characters.

Comment: This is likely a problem with your terminal program.